# ItextSharp doesn't display Japanese font

Tags: c#, itext

iTextSharp doesn't display Japanese font. I found a [solution](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/08/01/freely-fill-pdf-form-with-the-help-of-itext-or-itextsharp) but when I compile, I get an error saying:

> Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

Here's my source code:

```
BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch(serverPath + "\\lib\\iTextAsian.dll");
BaseFont.AddToResourceSearch(serverPath + "\\lib\\iTextAsianCmaps.dll");
BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont("STSong-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);    

using (Document document = new Document())
{
    using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(
        document, new FileStream(directoryOutPdf + nameOutPdf, FileMode.Create))
    )
    {
        document.Open();

        // generate one page per statement        
        for (int i = 0; i < countBlank.Count; i++)
        {                        
            // replace this with your PDF form template          
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath + @"\EmptyTemplateBankBlank_2012.pdf");
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                {
                    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                    form.SetFieldProperty("Info", "textfont", font, null);
                    form.SetField("Info", "_源泉徴収票");                                                                
                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                }
                reader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());

                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's because I didn't install the `STSong-Light` font. Unfortunately I could not find `STSong-Light` and, therefore, had to set `Stsong` font, but it still does not work.

```
String fontPath = Path.Combine(serverPath + "\\Fonts", "STSONG.ttf");

BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, "UniGB-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(baseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the SubstitutionFont after creating the PdfStamper:

```
stamper.AcroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(myFont.BaseFont);
```