# iTextSharp rendering Czech characters in AcroForm fields

Tags: c#, pdf, character-encoding, itext

I've got a few PDF template files with `AcroForm` fields in them, created using OpenOffice. When I try to fill the fields using `iTextSharp`:

`form.SetField(field.Key, String.Format(field.Value.FormatString, value));`

I get overlapping and missing characters in the flattened field:

[image]

I can embedd the `Arial` font in the finished PDF, but that swells the size a lot and it also means having to reset all the font properties which are already set on the fields (courtesy of Open Office).

When I fill the form manually in Adobe Reader, the text displays correctly.
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: you need to set the SubstitutionFont: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11202983/298573

Answer (score 0):

I am not a user of itextsharp but used itext in java quite a bit.So i think what you miss to mention here is adding substitution font.I as Pdf reader do not know is there font available or not to display its text character.As you are using AcroForm so there will be a object PdfStamper and you can also find a method similar PdfStamper.getWriter().getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true); as in itext java counterpart.Also form.addSubstitutionFont(BaseFont Obj for your language).You can add multiple because in java itext perspective it is an arraylist.Also when creating basefont using a font of .ttf file or .ttc file remember which encoding is used.For example to maintain chinese character as it is we use IDENTITY_H encoding,for arabic we use IDENTITY_V(V-Vertical Orientation,H-Horizontal Orientation).try this way if this helps(as a java itext user i don't know how much it conform with itextsharp)